# Modules not found in django

Tags: python, django

I want to make an application in django with two apps named apps and data.the "data" apps is placed within "apps".I had entered 'apps.data' in the Installed apps in "settings.py".when I run the devserver i got this error "no modules named apps.data".Any one please help me.

Comment: Have you added `apps` in installed apps?

Comment: Also, did you start the app as "data" and "apps" or as "apps.data" and "apps.apps"?

Comment: paste your settings .py

Comment: just put "data", if it is wrong again check your path root in settings.py

Comment: Did you use django-admin.py to create apps ? If not then you might have to add `__init__.py` file into every folder.

Answer (score 0):

what is the reason for nesting "data" app in "apps"? it is uncommon to nest one app inside of another when there are only two apps (unless you have some great reason to). suggestions:

create an apps app, and create a data model for it;

create an apps app, and a data app; (link them however through the models)

the answer to your problem is probably file structure, but your basic requirements for what you're asking is detailed in your app requirements.

Long story short.. what application are you trying to create?